# Haskell: Is it possible to use the abstract data type in pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, adt

Say I have an ADT called foo

```
data foo = N Integer | V Var | Div foo foo
```

Is there a way to use the ADT in pattern matching so I don't have to write out every possible combination of data types?

```
myfunc :: foo -> [Var]
myfunc (N _) = []
myfunc (V a) = [a]
myfunc (Div (foo) (foo)) = myfunc(foo) ++ myfunc(foo)
```

Is there a way to make something like this work so I don't have to write

```
myfunc (Div (N a) (N b)) = myfunc(N a) ++ myfunc(N b)
myfunc (Div (V a) (N b)) = myfunc(V a) ++ myfunc(N b)
myfunc (Div (N a) (V b)) = myfunc(N a) ++ myfunc(V b)
...
```

etc

Comment: Worth noting—ADT in the form created by `data` stands (confusingly) for "algebraic data type" while "abstract data type" means something else. In particular, you cannot (naturally) pattern match on an abstract data type in Haskell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, if you name things correctly, what you have works:

```
-- types have to begin with a capital letter, just like constructors
data Foo = N Integer | V Var | Div Foo Foo

myfunc :: Foo -> [Var]
myfunc (N _) = []
myfunc (V a) = [a]
myfunc (Div left right) = myfunc left ++ myfunc right
```

---

To test:

```
type Var = String -- Don't know what Var is, but it's a String for this example

> myfunc (Div (Div (V "A") (V "B")) (Div (V "C") (N 1)))
["A", "B", "C"]
```

Comment: Yes Var a string. Thanks for this, it was exactly what I needed, I didn't think to just give them arbitrary names.